# Trying to compare two text files in UTF-8 encoding to find and count similar words

Tags: python, utf-8, file-handling

I want to compare two text files that are in UTF-8 encoding, File 1 is a dictionary of words and file 2 contains a sentence. I want to find out the similar words that are present in File 1 and File 2.

```
import codecs
f1 = codecs.open('poswords.txt', 'r', 'UTF-8')
for line in f1:
    print(line)
f2 = codecs.open('0001b.txt', 'r', 'UTF-8')
words=set(line.strip() for line in f1)
for line in f2:
    word,freq =line.split()
    if word in words:
        print (word)
```

File 1(i.e Dictionary) contains

```
کرخت
ناجائز فائدہ
آب دیدہ
ابال
ابال کر پکانا
**ابالنا**
ابتدائ
ابتر
```

File 2 contains a sentence:

```
وفاقی وزیر اطلاعات فواد چودھری سے استعفیٰ لے لیا**ابالنا** گیا ہے
```

There are two common words in both the files i want to find them and count their occurences.
I want that it should return the similar words, but it returns an error saying that ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Not sure it's related to your problem, but the set `words` will be empty here, because you already consumed all lines of `f1` on lines 3 and 4.

Comment: Create a [mcve].  Give sample input that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thanks for the suggestion i have edited my problem, kindly check is it comprehensible now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to retrieve two values from `split`:

```
word, freq = line.split()
```

This will only work when there are exactly two words on a line (and by the variable naming, the second should apparently be a frequency count).

Another problem is that you consume all the lines from the first file when you `print` them. Once you have read all the lines from a handle, attempting to read more lines will simply return nothing. The simple fix is to both print and save each input word to the `words` set inside the same loop. (Maybe comment out the `print()`, actually; or `import logging` and change it to `logging.debug()`. This also ensures that the diagnostic output is not mixed with the program's regular standard output.)

In Python 3, UTF-8 should be the default encoding on most sane platforms (though this conspicuously and emphatically excludes Windows); maybe you don't need the explicit `codecs` at all.

Finally, you should be aware that Unicode can often represent the same string in multiple ways. I don't read Arabic, but briefly, for example, you can write "salaam" as a single glyph [U+FDF5](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fdf5/index.htm) or you can spell it out. Unicode normalization attempts to iron out any such wrinkles so you can be sure that text which displays the same is also written the same, and thus identical to Python's string comparison operator.

```
import codecs
import unicodedata

with codecs.open('poswords.txt', 'r', 'UTF-8') as f1:
    words = set()
    for line in f1:
        print(line)
        words.add(unicodedata.normalize('NFC', line.strip()))

with codecs.open('0001b.txt', 'r', 'UTF-8') as f2:
    for line in f2:
        for word in line.split():
            if unicodedata.normalize('NFC', word) in words:
                print (word)
```

Comment: I tried your code but i am getting this error "AttributeError: module 'unicodedata' has no attribute 'nomalize'". I'm very grateful for your response.

Comment: @DoorLasst Sorry about that; typo fixed.

Comment: Works great what if i have two dictionaries and one files of different sentences what changes are to be made in that case.

Comment: Read them both ...? If you genuinely can't figure it out, ask a new question (but perhaps review [the guidance](/help/how-to-ask)).